# Pagination in Mongoskin (skip + limit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

From looking at mongodb examples, I tried a few things, such as:

```
// returns an empty array
funnyPosts.find({limit:5}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Also tried

```
// returns { _construct_args: [],

console.log(db.collection('funny_posts').find().skip(3).limit(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to implement pagination with Node.js and MongoDB?

Your parameters in the wrong place (not the first param to `find()`). Here is my code for HackHall [GitHub link](https://github.com/azat-co/hackhall/blob/805eac26cac8dc65b534dcecd855ca5bf28048dc/routes/posts.js#L39):

```
exports.getPosts = function(req, res, next) {
  var limit = req.query.limit || LIMIT;
  var skip = req.query.skip || SKIP;
  req.db.Post.find({}, null, {
    limit: limit,
    skip: skip,
    sort: {
      '_id': -1
    }
  }, function(err, obj) {
    if (!obj) next('There are not posts.');
    obj.forEach(function(item, i, list) {
      if (req.session.user.admin) {
        item.admin = true;
      } else {
        item.admin = false;
      }
      if (item.author.id == req.session.userId) {
        item.own = true;
      } else {
        item.own = false;
      }
      if (item.likes && item.likes.indexOf(req.session.userId) > -1) {
        item.like = true;
      } else {
        item.like = false;
      }
      if (item.watches && item.watches.indexOf(req.session.userId) > -1) {
        item.watch = true;
      } else {
        item.watch = false;
      }
    });
    var body = {};
    body.limit = limit;
    body.skip = skip;
    body.posts = obj;
    req.db.Post.count({}, function(err, total) {
      if (err) next(err);
      body.total = total;
      res.json(200, body);
    });
  });
};
```

For more info look up my other posts on [webapplog.com](http://webapplog.com) and [Express.js Guide](http://expressjsguide.com).

Comment: @MarkRobson, you are very welcome. The first parameter in find() is a MUST. :-)